# VBA error handling if user clears contents

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following snippet of code which calculates the percent equivalent if a dollar value is entered or if a percent value is entered the equivalent dollar value is calculated. This works fine but if the user selects both the % and $ value and clears contents (instead of just updated the value to 0) it causes a run time error, which makes total sense based on the code. What I'm trying to determine is the best way to handle this type of error. Any creative thoughts on if both the $ and % values are selected and clear contents is clicked that it corrects to 0 without breaking the code?

```
If Not Application.Intersect(cell, target) Is Nothing Then
Select Case target.Column
    Case 37, 39, 43
        target.Offset(, 1).Value = target.Value / Range("V" & target.Row).Value
    Case 38, 40, 44
        target.Offset(, -1).Value = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((target.Value * Range("V" & target.Row).Value), -2)
    Case 41, 60
        target.Offset(, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((target.Value * Range("V" & target.Row).Value), -2)
    Case 42, 61
        target.Offset(, -1).Value = target.Value / Range("V" & target.Row).Value
End Select
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use On Error Resume Next and then check for an error and if found set the value to 0

```
On Error Resume Next 'jsut keep going if we have an error
If Not Application.Intersect(cell, target) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case target.Column
        Case 37, 39, 43
            target.Offset(, 1).Value = target.Value / Range("V" & target.Row).Value
        Case 38, 40, 44
            target.Offset(, -1).Value = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((target.Value * Range("V" & target.Row).Value), -2)
        Case 41, 60
            target.Offset(, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp((target.Value * Range("V" & target.Row).Value), -2)
        Case 42, 61
            target.Offset(, -1).Value = target.Value / Range("V" & target.Row).Value
    End Select
End If
If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'check for an error
    Err.Clear 'clear the error
    target.Offset(, -1).Value = 0 'set the value to 0
End If
```